# MongoDB: Advanced query on array

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

Suppose I have the following objects in my collection:

```
{id:'123', tags:['berry', 'apple']}
{id:'456', tags:['salad', 'tomatoe']}
{id:'789', tags:['bread', 'rice']}
```

My search term is "**Strawberry**". I want to find all objects, where one of the tags is part of search term. In this case it's the object with id '123', since 'berry' is part of 'Strawberry'.

I wanted to use Regex, like this (I'm using php btw):

```
$regex = new MongoRegex("/.*berry.*/i");
$results = $mongodb->data->find(array("tags" => array('$in' => array($regex))));
```

but the problem is that the regex is applied on the tags and not on the search result. So i'd need something like a reverse Regex.

Is a query like this somehow possible? Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
$search = "Strawberry";
$js = "function() { var i = 0; for (; i < this.tags.length; i++) { if ('".$search."'.indexOf(this.tags[i]) != -1) { return true; } } }";
$results = $mongodb->data->find($js);
```

That's OK for now, since the dataset isn't very large, but will be slow in the future.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry if this is still not clear.
My search Term is "Strawberry", not "berry". The php code I posted that contains the Regex was just to show that this is not a solution and does not work.

So again: My search term is "Strawberry" and *I want to find all objects, where on of the tags is part of the search term,* not the other way around

**UPDATE 2:**

To make it even clearer, in SQL this would be:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE 'Strawberry' LIKE CONCAT('%', tag, '%')
```

Comment: Huh? I don't get any of this. How does "strawberry" in a regex possibly match "berry"? You also have a term `$search` specified that you do not reference anywhere in code. Can you possibly edit this to make some actual sense that would help to resolve your problem?

Comment: Okay so you have actually changed part of this so "berry" as a search term makes sense. But seriously `/berry/i` is the same thing as the contrived statement being made. So it still is not clear what you expect as a result. Do you just want "berry" as your only result, without the other array member?

Comment: The term I have is "Strawberry". I want to find all objects where a tag is part of my search term. "berry" is part of "Strawberry", so every object that has "berry" as a tag should be part of the result.

Comment: I have got solution for it in mongo shell, please check and let me know if it solves your issue @DenisStad

Comment: My search term is "Strawberry" and not "berry". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You have changed around what you are searching several times here. It was my initial comment. What code determines you are looking for "berry" out of "Stawberry"? And if that is what your actual question is then you have touched on a subject way to broad for here. Oh and if you want to "notify" someone of your comment on your own question  , then "tag" them as has been shown in at least one comment here.

Comment: @DenisStad What you want is too broad, by what "logic" shouldn't `rry` get matched? What about `y`? Or a simple `r`? The simplest way I see is to put `?` after each character to make everything optional and then filter the results by length. For example, you want a hit only if it's 3 characters or longer. Do not forget to anchor your regex. It would finally look like `/^s?t?r?a?w?b?e?r?r?y?$/i`. This should even give a hit on `rawberry`, `raw` etc...

Comment: @NeilLunn No I haven't changed my search term. Right from there start there was "My search term is "Strawberry". I want to find all objects, where one of the tags is part of search term." The only thing I changed is that I added "$search = "Strawberry";" since you asked where that came from.

Comment: @NeilLunn There is no logic that is looking for "berry" out of "Strawberry". That is my question. If I had strawberry in my tags and I'd search for "berry" then this would be pretty simple, but I want it to be the other way around. And why is that to broad for here? Any links to further reading?

Comment: If you you'd have an entry for "raw" would that be a match for "strawberry" as well? And how about "ray" ? That's kinda part of strawberry as well, if you skip some letters. How is the relation defined?

Comment: @Nanne yes, "raw" would match strawberry. "ray" wouldn't, since "ray" is not part of "strawberry". ( it's not "strayberry"). The tag must be part of the search term

Answer (score 0):

This query will match strawberry if you have in tags

```
 db.collection.aggregate(
     [
       {$unwind: "$tags"}, 
       {$match : {tags: /.*berry.*/i  }}
     ]
    )
```

**Tested output**'

```
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("537373c17c3639c32fe515fb"),
                    "id" : "123",
                    "tags" : "berry"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("537375337c3639c32fe515fe"),
                    "id" : "789",
                    "tags" : "strawberry"
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
```

}

In terms of PHP,

```
$result = $mongodb->aggregate(array(
    array(
      '$unwind' => "$tags",
    ),
    array(
      '$match' => array(
          'tags' => /.*berry.*/i
      ),
    ),
));
```